# React Native selectionColor is not changing the Cursor Color

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I need to change the cursor color of the react-native `TextInput`. I am using the `selectionColor` props and setting the color but it is not changing the cursor color of the `TextInput`. I have found a workaround for and added the following code to my `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml` file

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/black</item>
```

This works but its sets the global color for all the screens and this does not work for my screens with a black background.  Here is how I am using the text input.

```
<TextInput
    selectionColor={'black'}
    placeholderTextColor="gray"
    textBreakStrategy="highQuality"
    placeholder="12"
    style={styles.input__style}
    keyboardType="number-pad" />
```

Comment: selectionColor  is work in android

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/b5VMtIF7l <- here is my example

Comment: What worked for me is that I wasn't setting the `color` for the TextInput. Once I have set the color the selectionColor started working fine. Idk why but that's what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Go to android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

add the below line it's changed the cursor color.

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">yourColorHere</item>
```